# sorting player names by their scores in android game

Tags: java, android, sorting, scoring

I am making a scrabble app and i want to make make a system where players can view their scores along with names. The scores should be arranged from highest to lowest. the output should look like this:
      **Name**    **Score**

```
Kathy   150
Charm   140
Albert  130
Arvin   120
Angelo  110
```

I am trying to do this using array and I am having a hard time making this work.

```
int score[]= new int[4];
        score[0]= 120;
        score[1]= 130;
        score[2]= 140;
        score[3]= 150;

        String names[] = new String[4];
        names[0]= "albert";
        names[1]= "arvin";
        names[2]= "charm";
        names[3]= "kathy";

        Player[] players = new Player[names.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            players[i] = new Player(names[i], score[i]);

            show.setText((CharSequence) players[i]);

        }

        Arrays.sort(players, new PlayerComparator());


   class PlayerComparator implements Comparator<Player> {
 public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
    return p1.getScore() < p2.getScore() ? -1
            : p1.getScore() > p2.getScore() ? 1 : 0;

}
}

public class Player {

private String name;

private int score;

public Player(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public String toString() {
    return "name=" + name + "; score=" + score;
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me on what to use and guide me to achieve this goal? thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where's your code? What structure is in place to hold this data?

Comment: Please post the code you already have.

Comment: Use `objects`, `ArrayList`, `Comparable` and override `compareTo`. Problem solved. Try to code using these, and if stuck up anywhere, get back here.

Comment: ok..i will edit my post..

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a `class Score implements Comparable` which holds username and a number.
2. Implement `compareTo()` for `Score`, `Comparable` interface needs that.
3. Insert all your Scores into for example `ArrayList`.
4. Call [`Collections.sort(yourList)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).
5. Be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use arrays to do it, you will need to keep track of 2 separate arrays both of type integers, first will be for scores and second will be for their positions. Use the second array's values to keep track of each player and their respective score. Depending on the language you are using there are usually sort functions and algorithms that you can use from standard libraries to perform the sorting from highest to lowest or whatever.

If you are using Java I would recommend using a HashMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html
This would eliminate using 2 arrays and would be simplier i think
This is why I would recommend looking into using a HashMap it would make it simpler 
Hope this helps